# Alternative To Altiris SVS For OS X?

Tags: macos, software-rec, snapshot, sandbox, altiris-svs

Is there an alternative to Altiris S.V.S. (Altiris Software Virtualization Suite) for OS X? Something that can revert all changes an application has made to the system.

Comment: Need a program = http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
Need help with a program = http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know what files changed and lose their original values is to look at the fsevenets that are generated during the update. [Apple programming doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

You can see them using tools such as [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this requires planning before install.

Take a time machine backup just before and just after the install. The later backup will just o[y over the changes.

If on Leopard there is a [tool that will show the changes](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:misc:tms)

Comment: Hm, that's a little overkill imho.  I don't want to create a full backup to just rollback 2 files chaged.

Comment: How are you going to revert to old files that have been changed?